# JS Works in Firefox but not loading in chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser

Our js player loads correctly in firefox but doesnt run in Chrome or IE.
I tried the other workarounds mentioned on stackoverflow for the following errors:

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'fancybox'

4event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.

But doesnt work.  I tried loading js file asynchronously but it just doesnt seem to load in chrome and IE.

Here's our page URL: http://www.iorad.com/?a=app.htmlplayer&accessCode=GUEST&remote=true&module=3225

Pressing the green play button should open the next slide, which you can see in firefox.

Comment: Please include code in the question. Referencing a broken external website is wrong as it won't tell anything about this question when you fix/upgrade/delete it

Comment: I tried it on chrome and before the "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'fancybox'" y see these ones: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" that points to some supposedly html-commented lines at some cold fusion js generated code in the html page: http://cl.ly/GVEi

Answer (score 0):

The only errors I get are: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment". Use javascript comments syntax instead of html inside the  tag.